# Junit,Debugging,Sync in Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit, synchronization

lets say you have following classes:

```
public class A {

public void run() { 
    synchronized(B.class) {
       System.out.println("A: here");       
    }
}
}

public class B {

public void run() {

    synchronized(B.class) {
       System.out.println("B: here");       
    }
}
}
```

So the code inside the sync block for obj a and obj b is synced, if its running on the same jvm.

I want to test the sync, so i have a JUnit Testcase for Class A and Class B.

I run the two Testcases over eclipse via the Eclipse Menu DebugAs->JUnitTest.

The result is, that there is no synchronization. Is this because Eclipse creates a new JVM for every started JUnit Testcase ?

If yes, is there a way to test the sync ?

Thank you already

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"The result is, that there is no synchronization"_? If the output contains lines other than `A: here` and `B: here`, the mixing happens after the synchronized blocks. (In your example, `synchronized(B.class)` only guarantees that one or no thread executes code of the two blocks at the same time.) _Run/Debug As JUnit Test_ starts one new JVM (see launch configuration _JRE_ tab).

Comment: I have a breakpoint at System.out.println("B: here"); and at System.out.println("A: here"); When i run both Testcases i can reach both breakpoints.

Comment: Do you run both test cases via a test suite that contains both test cases (-> one JVM) or both test cases separately (-> two JVMs)?

Comment: Both test cases separatly. Thank you for your hints. I have found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was running the Testcases seperatley.
With this it worked:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Class[] cls = {A.class,B.class};
    // Parallel among classes
    JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.classes(), cls);
}
```